# How can I apply two styles using moredelim?

Tags: listings, delimiters

I'm using `lstlisting` with `moredelim` to color sections of the listing.

Now, I'd like to also underline the same sections.

I found that I cannot simply add `\underbar`.

```
\lstdefinestyle{foo}{
  moredelim=[is][\underbar\color{red}]{@}{@}, % compiler error
}
```

Using both separately had one of them being ignored.

```
\lstdefinestyle{foo}{
  moredelim=[is][\underbar]{@}{@},
  moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{@}{@}, % only one of these is in effect
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply invert `\underbar` with `\color{red}`

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{foo}{
  moredelim=[is][\color{red}\underbar]{@}{@}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=foo]
@Hello@
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Do you know the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: @mafu You can't write `{\underbar\color{red} Hallo}` neither outside a listing...